# Django Cannot Connect to Remote MySQL Server

Tags: python, mysql, django, ssh, pycharm

I am running a Django and attempting to connect to a MySQL server at my university. 
First of all:
In order to connect the database, I normally SSH into a remote server (with authentication) of theirs, and then run MySQL and enter my MySQL authentications.
This works without an issue, in Terminal as well as DataGrip.
Now, using PyCharm, I have installed mysqlclient in the intepreter and changed my 
settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': '[DB_NAME]',
       'USER': '[DB_USERNAME]',
       'PASSWORD': '[DB_PASSWORD]',
       'HOST': '[REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS HOSTING MYSQL]',
       'PORT': '3306',
  }
}
```

Also using PyCharm, I have even opened up a data source in the Data Sources Tool Window and connected through SSH tunnel and MySQL authentication to the database. This is successful, and it is possible to make queries.

However, I try to run:

```
manage.py check
```

and I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '[REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS HOSTING MYSQL]' (60)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 43, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/skillapop/Desktop/streamcity_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 68, in handle
fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1283, in check
errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1358, in _check_fields
errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 913, in check
errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 219, in check
errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 322, in _check_backend_specific_checks
return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 49, in check_field
field_type = field.db_type(self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 644, in db_type
return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 174, in data_types
if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 385, in mysql_version
with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 591, in temporary_connection
cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
return self._cursor()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '[REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS HOSTING MYSQL]' (60)")
```

It is also important to note that I HAVE connected a Django project to this exact same server and database before in a test run. Now, that test project and the new project does NOT connect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you actually keep `[REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS HOSTING MYSQL]` as host adress ? try to replace this and any other connection parameter needed in the database settings

Comment: From the machine you're running Django on, can you connect? You can test with telnet to see if it hangs or connects: `telnet [REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS HOSTING MYSQL] 3306` and see if it connects or just hangs on `Connecting...`

Comment: Yes I can connect to the remote server on my local machine using terminal as well as linking it as a "Data Source" in PyCharm. It's simply my Django project that will not connect..